# Need java regex to match the below string

Tags: java, regex

What is the java regex to match the below pattern?

```
<anyString>.<5 or 10>.anyNumber.anyNumber
```

Here 5 and 10 are numbers.

Comment: This is a trivial problem to solve with regular expressions. I think you would be better served if you tried to solve the problem rather than wait an hour or two for someone else to solve it for you. Regular expressions aren't hard (especially one like this). If you can write code in any language, you can learn regular expressions with just a couple hours of study and practice.

Comment: Have a look at http://txt2re.com/. It gives a very good starting point: http://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=string.5.123.456&3&5&6

Answer (score 6):

```
.*\.(?:5|10)\.\d+\.\d+
```

should work.

**Explanation:**

```
.*        # any number of characters (except newlines)
\.        # literal dot
(?:5|10)  # 5 or 10
\.        # literal dot
\d+       # one or more digits
\.        # literal dot
\d+       # one or more digits
```

Remember that, if you use it in Java, you need to escape the backslashes when constructing the regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".*\\.(?:5|10)\\.\\d+\\.\\d+");
```

Comment: Wouldn't this match if there is only a "1" or "0" in that 5 or 10 section?

Comment: @Sachin: No. `(?:5|10)` matches `5` or `10`, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that i read your intention correctly this should work:

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?\\.(?:5|10)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)");
    Matcher m;

    m = p.matcher(".5.11.10");
    m.matches(); // == true
    m.group(1).equals("11");
    m.group(2).equals("10");


    m = p.matcher("hannib al.10.11.12");
    m.matches(); // == true
    m.group(1).equals("11");
    m.group(2).equals("12");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the example valid string `.5.1.1`

This form should do the trick

`\.(5|10)\.[0-9]\.[0-9]`

or if the second two numbers can have more than one character i.e. `.10.123.1234`

`\.(5|10)\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*`

Comment: `(5)|(10)` needs to be `(5|10)` or the alternation will not work as intended.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Good spot, as currently written this matches `.5` or `10.123.123` - Editing accordingly